# What is the purpose of the "grounding" tab/wire on a 3-prong to 2-prong adapter?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

We've probably all seen [these guys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheater_plug)...

[image: 3-prong to 2-prong adapter]

They come in handy when you need to plug something with three prongs, into something with two prongs.  What I've never understood was, what the heck is the "grounding" tab for?  It's meant to have the cover plate mounting screw through it. But why?

[image: Adapter Installation]

Is this really designed as a grounding device, or is it there simply as an attachment means to insure the thing doesn't fall out of the receptacle?

Comment: I can't authoritatively answer this, but it is my impression that the grounding tab comes in contact with the coverplate screw, that is in contact with the metal frame of the receptacle, which is in contact with the metal box, which is hopefully grounded to the metal conduit that carries the wire to the box from the breaker.  The conduit of course is grounded to the electrical panel.

Comment: @maple_shaft In a perfect world, but what about those 2 prong receptacles that are supplied by cable with no grounding means (which may be a large portion of 2 prong receptacles)?  Also, if the receptacle is not a self grounding type (which it's not since it's 2 prong), the yoke is not an acceptable grounding means.

Comment: It can be... I have measured decent continuity between the plate screw and grounded conductor in older homes where I knew the box was metal and it was grounded to the panel. It is certainly more likely to offer ground fault protection than the cheater plug without a ground tab.  Why are these things legal anyway?  Surely the NEC doesn't put its stamp of approval on this?

Comment: @maple_shaft There may be continuity, but it's not *designed* to carry current, and is not an *accepted* grounding means.

Comment: Nor is the human body designed to carry current, but that wouldn't stop it from getting electrocuted when touching a desktop case plugged into a cheater plug that has developed a ground fault.  That tab might save someones life regardless.  Lesser of two evils I guess.

Comment: Strange that you *ask the question* and then *immediately argue against it.*

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'll argue against it's use, until somebody can provide enough evidence to persuade me the other way. And by evidence I of course mean something from a reliable source.

Comment: Arguing against its use does not have any relevance to your question. The purpose (which is what you asked) is to connect to ground. If you don't like them, rewire your house, add GFCIs and labels, or whatever suits you. I haven't needed one in 30 years...(and that house had grounds, just not many outlets with grounds.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'm simply playing devils advocate, to try and inspire a good answer.  Maple_Shaft had a fairly good answer in his comment, and I was trying to get him to expand on it.

Comment: @maple_shaft Your comments would make a good answer. Explaining how it would work with both metallic and nonmetallic cable would make it a great answer.

Comment: @maple_shaft Is this something NEC or UL would have to approve?  If unapproved, what stops them from being sold regardless?  I've always believed your chain of connections was the expectation, and beyond the control of the adapter to verify.  But seeing the entire chain typed out, I'm now skeptical about how often it ever really happens.  (disregarding how often I see these in use by people who didn't bother to unscrew the faceplate screw and connect them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Grounding from plug to Box

Looking at the second picture in the question, makes the grounding path to the box evident.

[image: Grounding path to box]

While the yoke of the device may not be a great (or approved) grounding path (unless it's a self grounding device), it may well serve as a grounding path in an emergency. Which when it comes down to it, is the purpose of the equipment grounding conductor.

## Grounding from box to earth

In some situations conductors leading to the box may be either in metallic conduit, or cable assemblies sheathed in a metallic covering.  In some cases, these metallic pathways can provide and adequate grounding path. In these situations, the grounding ring on the adapter can indeed provide and adequate grounding path.

Unfortunately, there are a lot of situations where nonmetallic cable is used to supply nongrounding type receptacles.  In these cases, the grounding ring will not provide a path to ground.

## Potential Hazards

Without an adequate path to ground from the box, this setup could actually be **more** dangerous.

### Short to ground inside the box

If for some reason the ungrounded (hot) conductor comes into contact with the metallic box, the box can become energized.  If this adapter is connected, the grounding conductor of the plugged in device can also be energized. In this case, if the grounding conductor is attached to a metallic outer covering of the plugged in device. The outer covering can be energized, and becomes a potential shock/electrocution hazard.

### Inadequate grounding path

If the box is supplied using older armored cable, the cable sheathing may actually be a high resistance path to ground.  This could lead to heating of the cable sheath, in some cases to the point of ignition of surrounding building materials. Modern armored cables provide a low resistance path to ground, and are often approved to be used as a grounding means. So if newer cable is used, this may not be a problem.

### Broken grounding path

The box containing the receptacle may be supplied using modern cabling, and a grounding path may be present. However, the modern cabling may be connected to older cabling that does not provide a grounding path. In this case, fault current will follow the grounding path back to the junction between old and new cabling, and lead to potential hazards at that location.

## tl;dr

In some cases these devices work as intended, and provide an adequate path to ground.  In other cases they do not, and can potentially introduce other hazards.  Though we must keep in mind, the equipment grounding conductor is a safety device. Under normal operating conditions, this path will never have current flowing through it.  Because of this, the dangers from a device like this are limited.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's designed as a ground attachment. No, it's not simply to keep it from falling out, as evidenced by the style you haven't shown that provides a pigtail green wire, and the fact that the terminal in question is electrically connected to the ground pin of the receptacle side of the device.

[image: Pigtail adapter]

While it is true that this will not always result in a ground, and may (I haven't got time to sift through code, nor code on a computer to sift through) not result in a ground approved by code, it is, nevertheless, what it's there for, and in quite a few cases it does, in fact result in a ground - whether or not you like it.

Comment: In the days of Metal Conduit, Armored BX and Metal Electrical Boxes, it was a ground for the inserted three wire device. Your conduit system was supposed to attach to a cold water pipe bonded to ground with a ground rod. The center screw in the cover plate attached to the metal bracket the sockets attached to and grounded to the electrical box via the two screws that held the socket there.

Answer (score 6):

Plausible deniability. I've always regarded these adapters as a 2-to-3-prong converter, rather than a proper grounding mechanism, and here's why:

In every outlet I've encountered without a third (ground) prong, there is no ground wire. Sometimes (my parents' house) there is, but for whatever reason the ground wire is cut off and unused. Thus, the electrical box itself isn't even grounded.

The screw holding the face plate on is electrically connected to the outlet box, and if it's not grounded, then there's not much point in using the screw holding the face plate on as a ground.

The companies who make these grounding adapters probably also know this, but they can't really get away with providing 2-to-3-prong adapter without providing some way to still connect ground. So they provide a way to connect it to something that *should* be grounded, but often isn't. In this way, it's not their fault if something bad happens because your house wiring is faulty.

If you do happen to have a 2-prong outlet in a properly grounded box, then the little ground tab or wire *will* actually provide ground continuity, as intended.

So, the answer is that the grounding tab is meant as a way to connect electrically to something that in turn should be grounded (but might not be). It's not meant as a secure attachment mechanism, though it may seem that way because of the use of a faceplate screw.

Comment: I have come across one that didn't even have a grounding tab.

Comment: @Brad 1. Research if the manufacturer still exists and if so, if the company is wealthy. 2. Ensure you have purchase receipts, warranty registration card filled out, etc. 3. Operate some machinery using the adapter, perhaps something that doesn't have safe wiring (wink, wink). 4. Sue for damages and profit.

Comment: Based on the design I would say that the latest it would have been produced was in the 1970's. ( It had 1940's 1950's styling. ) I don't remember any identifiable markings on it either.

Comment: _plausible deniability_ Nice conspiracy theory, works if the house wiring used properly installed and grounded metal boxes and conduit. Which is what this is supposed to be used with.

Comment: I would think stores should sell adapters with a GFCI built in.  Given that even the cheapest hair dryer will have a GFCI built into the cord, the cost of the GFCI part can't be all that great, and the safety advantages would be *huge*.

Answer (score 3):

Many older houses with 2-prong outlets use the sheathing of their [BX or AC cables](http://www.seatekco.com/images/bx-02cw.jpg) to ground the metal cases.  This is [not a very effective ground](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/13286/), but it is better than nothing.

These adapters with the grounding tab are a much cheaper and easier alternative to rewiring the entire house, yet still provide (marginally) more safety than using the adapters [without a grounding tab](http://cache3.smarthome.com/images/44084gy.jpg).

As the site's expert on electrical matters, I'm sure you knew this already, so I'm curious why you asked this question ;)

Comment: Just because I know the answer (sort of), doesn't mean I can't ask the question.

Comment: One of the great things about SE sites is that you can ask a question (even if you know the answer) because you want to either a) answer it yourself as a reference for others, b) get additional answers to elaborate and expand on something, or c) you just want to get more internet points!

Comment: @Tester101: Fair enough.  I hope you didn't read that in an offending tone - I was just curious, that's all.

Comment: It is [ok](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16933/1337) to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16930/1337). I advocate [waiting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16936/1337) a while though.

Answer (score 1):

These are "officially intended" for cases where the sockets are 2-prong, *but yet, the receptacle is grounded.*  The idea is to get proper ground from the receptacle cover plate screw, which would work *if* the receptacle was grounded.

**Obviously, this situation is *imaginary***.  If an electrician went to all the trouble to use the more expensive /2+ground cable in 1964, he certainly would have fit the then-impressive 3-prong receptacle, as a *selling point* for his effort, and there would be no need for this adapter.

So this is called a *cheater* for a reason -- it's *actually* used to plug 3-prong things in locations which are actually not grounded.  **Which, indeed, is playing with fire.**  For instance the one in your photo allows polarized devices to be plugged in (taller neutral slot), but its pins are not polarized, breaking polarization!

Now the modern age gives us an alternative here, and that's to fit GFCI protection to the ungrounded circuit (a breaker, deadface or GFCI+receptacle here or upstream), with a "No Equipment Ground" sticker.  That will provide all the shock protection of a grounded outlet, but none of the equipment protection (hence the sticker).

Comment: Actually, the case of 2-prong yet ground available would happen back then if they were using BX or conduit -- it's only imaginary for receptacles wired with pre-ground NM.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I would have expected those to be upgraded the moment someone cared.  That's like, low hanging fruit!

Comment: +1 for the "imaginary" part.  What I find puzzling is why there aren't commonplace adapters with a GFCI built in, or even purpose-designed non-ground-to-three-prong GFCI outlets which, instead of leaving ground floating, have a current-limited connection to neutral (so that a hot-to-chassis fault will trip the GFCI immediately rather than waiting for someone to supply an alternate ground path).

Comment: @supercat There are, in fact, adapter cords which provide a GFCI inline.  There's a bit more to it than sticking a GFCI in a 2-gang steel box and hanging a pendant off it (thought of that).